# Excepción al ejecutar .jar desde terminal

Tags: groovy

Buen dia estoy tratando de ejecutar un .jar desde terminal, pero me esta arrojando la siguiente excepcion:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.lang.GroovyObject

Cabe mencionar que tengo la libreria `groovy-all-2.3.8` y en su contenido si puedo ver dicha clase.

El stack de la excepción es el siguiente:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/lang/GroovyObject
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
>       at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       at mx.pade.integracion.conector.Main.main(Main.java:24)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.lang.GroovyObject
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       ... 13 more

Alguien que pueda orientarme con este caso, de antemano muchas gracias!!

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar el código para tener una mejor idea de lo que está haciendo tu programa?

Comment: en donde tienes la librería? es accesible por el .jar